# how to define a private event [Port Mootools to jquery]

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, mootools, mouseevent

I'am a big mootools fan. 
But now I have to port a mootools-snipe to jquery and I do not get it.

I' am using this code:

```
var  prev_m_x = 0;
var  prev_m_y = 0;

window.addEvent('mousemove',function(e){
            prev_m_x=e.page.x;
            prev_m_y=e.page.y;
     });

Element.Events.enterfromleft ={
    base: 'mouseover',
    condition: function(event){
        var elpos = this.getPosition();
        if(prev_m_x<=elpos.x)  return true; return;
    }
};

Element.Events.enterfromright ={
    base: 'mouseover',
    condition: function(event){
        var elpos = this.getPosition();
        if(prev_m_x>=(elpos.x+this.getWidth())) return true; return;
    }
};
```

to define my events.

In the end I'am using this events in the following way:

```
el.addEvents({
    'enterfromleft':function(e){
          ...
    },
    'enterfromright':function(e){

    } ...
```

I tried to do something like this in jquery but without success. Please see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tFw89/33/

What I have to do in jquery to define a private event?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: you will have to write a plugin in jquery

Comment: private event == custom event?

Comment: private event == custom event == "YES"

Comment: The daddy on this sort of stuff is Brandon Aaron - try [this](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/03) for starters.

Comment: ..... and Arun P Johny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [write a plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

```
(function($) {

    var prev_m_x = 0;
    var prev_m_y = 0;

    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        prev_m_x = e.pageX;
        prev_m_y = e.pageY;
    });

    $.fn.mouseMove = function(type) {

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.on('mouseover', function(e) {
                if (prev_m_x <= e.pageX) {
                    $this.trigger('enterfromleft')
                } else {
                    $this.trigger('enterfromright')
                }
            });
        });

    };
})(jQuery);

$('#myButton').on('enterfromleft', function(){
    console.log('enterfromleft')
});
$('#myButton').on('enterfromright', function(){
    console.log('enterfromright')
});
$('#myButton').mouseMove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mRnun/4/)

A fix related to tracking mouse move, register mouse move event on document, rather than to the element.

Comment: thx: on the first view it looks quite good. But the console.log seems to show not the correct statustext. not only left and right. It shows something undepended where the mouse comes in

Comment: probably my conditions got mixed up

Comment: sorry if you make a mouse -in and -out console shows results undepending where you come from

Comment: Yes, the paradigm needs somehow to reject 'enterfromrTop' and 'enterfromBottom' conditions, though it's hard to see that the original  mootools-snipe didn't suffer the same issue because the paradigm seems to be identical.

Comment: It's something else. The mousemove which keeps track of x and y is only registered on the target element, not the document. So the previous position would always be inside the button, hence when entering from the "right" it thinks it's from the left...

Comment: I have it.

Please have a look here. 

http://jsfiddle.net/mRnun/8/

I think it's done.

Thanks to Arun.

Comment: @arun one more question: In mootools it is a general event. In jquery i have to bind it with $('#container').mouseMove(); to a special element. If I have a lot of elements, isn't it better to have a general event?

Comment: you will see my problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/mRnun/11/

with one container it worlks well: http://jsfiddle.net/mRnun/10/